# How to draw a line graph in iOS Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

Im working on line graph, im newly working on line graph concept. I had search some code in GitHub but i didn't get the perfect line graph. please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some code and any background research you have already done?

Comment: It's not really a concept as much as it is a fact of getting the data and drawing it... start your search with UIBezierPath if you're not sure where to start looking or Core Graphics / Core Animation

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code of how to draw a plot with a datasource. Of course you have to make the graph first and implement all relevant methods before doing so.

```
// 1 - Set up the three plots
self.aaplPlot = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor redColor] horizontalBars:NO];
self.aaplPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolAAPL;
self.googPlot = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor greenColor] horizontalBars:NO];
self.googPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolGOOG;
self.msftPlot = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor blueColor] horizontalBars:NO];
self.msftPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolMSFT;
// 2 - Set up line style
CPTMutableLineStyle *barLineStyle = [[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc] init];
barLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor lightGrayColor];
barLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.5;
// 3 - Add plots to graph
CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
CGFloat barX = CPDBarInitialX;
NSArray *plots = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.aaplPlot, self.googPlot, self.msftPlot, nil];
for (CPTBarPlot *plot in plots) {
    plot.dataSource = self;
    plot.delegate = self;
    plot.barWidth = CPTDecimalFromDouble(CPDBarWidth);
    plot.barOffset = CPTDecimalFromDouble(barX);
    plot.lineStyle = barLineStyle;
    [graph addPlot:plot toPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];
    barX += CPDBarWidth;
}
```

Check [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2) for more information on how to make and draw a graph with `core-plot`.

Comment: To the downvoter: If you vote down at least tell me how I can improve my answer or why my answer isn't appropriate. Thank you.